# Zend Framework is using html files as view script instead of phtml

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-view, zend-framework

We had a developer code for us, and he did it in php. When we were studying the code, we noticed that all the views have **html** as their extension instead of **phtml**. We checked by renaming a file to phtml, and it gives an error. What's amazing is that they have not done this in the app, they have done it at Zend Level.

***IF I replace the zend framework in the library directory with a fresh download, the app stops working. saying that the view was not found***

Does anyone know how they did this (modified ZF to search for html instead of phtml files)?

One more thing:
all over the place, he's using a variable `$this->baseURL` (not `$this->baseUrl()` as provided by zF) which holds the base url. Its not a helper, I checked and can't seem to find the declaration anywhere in the code, but still magically it is available through all the controllers and views. How did they implement?  I did a search through all the files, but nowhere is `baseURL` defined or the option `baseURL` written to `AUTH`, `STORAGE`, or anything. So how did he get to this? Modify the zf again?

Comment: Check the .htaccess and the Bootstrap to see if there're rules about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may have changed the Zend Layout class file `Zend/Layout.php`.

You can check for `protected $_viewSuffix = 'html';` instead of phtml which is the default.

You can fix this by adding the following to your bootstrap so you can upgrade the Zend Framework files.

```
protected function _initViewSuffix()
{
    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setViewSuffix('html');
}
```

As for the $baseURL variable, this could have been set via a plugin, or action helper.

If you get the view object you can do something like `$view->baseURL = 'xxx';` to make it available.  This can be done from a plugin or action helper.

Hope that helps.

Comment: getMvcInstance was null for me, but using the other response with Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker worked

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php` where you should find

```
protected $_viewSuffix = 'html'
```

Better ways to change the view suffix is adding this to the `application/Bootstrap.php`

```
/**
 * Set default view suffix to .html (see http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5301)
 */
protected function _initViewSuffix()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setViewSuffix('html');
}
```

Or you can change it by this init method in all controllers

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setViewSuffix('html');
}
```

`Zend_Layout` as mentioned by **drew010** only changes the suffix of layouts and not of views.